# How does Rails 7 locate the Ruby executable?

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, path, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm new to Ruby and Rails, and my rails installation cannot run in the CLI because it is looking for Ruby in the wrong place.

TLDR question - How can I point rails to my ruby installation?

Here is the command I ran and it's output.  It is looking for ruby in the wrong directory.

```
$ rails -v
/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails: line 6: /c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/ruby: No such file or directory
```

I'm using an installation of ruby from the `rubyinstaller-devkit-3.2.2-1-x64`.  Once that was done I installed rails using the command `gem install rails`.  I followed the [installation instructions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) from the Rails community, right up until it came time to check the version of my installation.

I've done some searching and learned that the `.bat` files can define where rails looks for ruby or other packages, and that they can be run independently.
I can run `rails.bat` like so and get the following result:

```
$ ~/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails.bat -v
Rails 7.0.7.2
```

So I opened `rails.bat` and it contains this

```
@ECHO OFF
@ruby.exe "%~dpn0" %*
```

I read up on batch files and their syntax, and I edited `rails.bat` so that I could see what command was being run.  Here is the output from that experiment:

```
$ ~/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails.bat -v

C:\Users\<username>\workspace\ruby-work>ruby.exe "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\rails" -v
Rails 7.0.7.2
```

While searching I saw a great deal of consternation from Rails users when some installer had an incorrect path hardcoded, but I don't see that hardcoding here.  Further, they seemed to be solving their problem by correcting the relevant `.bat` files (this was for an older version of Rails and Ruby).  But when I edit my `.bat` files, and re-run `rails -v` I get the same output - it always looks in the same directory, no matter what path I define in the `.bat` files.

**How can I point Rails to the directory containing my ruby installation?**

Finally here is some version and location info which I hope is helpful.  I am running on Windows 10.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
$ gem -v
3.4.10
$ which ruby
/c/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby
$ which rails
/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails
$ ~/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails.bat -v
Rails 7.0.7.2
```

Edit:
Noting here that the commands above were issued in a bash shell.
Reviewing my PATH, the only ruby-related inclusion I see is this.

```
C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;
```

I don't have any further environment variables related to ruby development defined as of yet.

Comment: Don't know the answer (yet), but I would look (and perhaps edit) the file `/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails` instead. You might be able to fix the problem just by editing that file. What does it look like?

Comment: Whats your PATH look like? What are al your Ruby environment variables? Are you using a Ruby version manager? Are you running under Cygwin or Windows' Linux susbsytem?  Debugging idiosyncratic setups without a lot more detail is rarely possible.

Comment: @To
I've added the relevant PATH and env variable info.

Comment: @Casper Interesting thought, I hadn't opened it before.  Now that I have, it's a relatively short file.  I'll back it up and tinker a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion by @Casper I opened the `/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/rails` file to see if editing it would be any help.  Inside I found the following snippet that appears to target the ruby executable:

```
=begin
bindir="${0%/*}"
exec "$bindir/ruby" "-x" "$0" "$@"
=end
```

By changing the value of `bindir` like so, I can run rails commands through the command line successfully:
`bindir="C:/Ruby32-x64/bin"`

The downside here is that I'll need to manually update this path any time I need to update or otherwise change the version of Ruby.  This feels like more of a workaround, but it got me up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the `rails.bat` file is hardcoded to look for Ruby in the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` directory. You can fix this by editing the `rails.bat` file and changing the path to your Ruby installation.

Find the line in `rails.bat` that says:

```
ruby.exe "%~dpn0" %*
```

Change the path to your Ruby installation, like this:

```
ruby.exe "C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby" %*
```

Now, when you run the `rails -v` command, it should be able to find your Ruby installation and print the version number.

Alternatively, you need to check that PATH environmental variable includes the correct path to your Ruby installation.

Comment: Thanks for the response borisano.  I did try editing the path in `rails.bat` - none of the changes I tried (including the one you suggest) allowed the rails command itself to find the ruby.exe.  Definitely worth a try, though.  I'll share some of the path edits I tried -

```
/c/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe "%/c/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby" %*
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe "%~dpn0" %*
ruby.exe "C:\Ruby32-x64\bin" %*
```

And speaking of PATH - I did verify that my PATH env variable is pointing to my Ruby installation correctly.